# android gps distance in textview shows previous distance when application run second time

Tags: android, gps

I have an application, which calculate distance after every 100 meters. There is a button and a text view. When I click the button and start walking, the distance shows in the text view. After reaching my destination when I click the button second time, application stop. But when I start the application second time, it shows in the text view, the previous distance but it should be 0 there.

Here is my activity:

```
public class Gps extends Activity {

TextView display;
Button start;
boolean doubleclick = false;
AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation;
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;
double lastLon = 0;
double lastLat = 0;
double distance;
Animation animRotate;
TextView startStop;

LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.anim_rotate);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!doubleclick) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                enabled = lm
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (loc == null) {
                        display.setText("No GPS location found");
                    } else {
                        // set Current latitude and longitude
                        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

                    }
                    // Set the last latitude and longitude
                    startStop.setText("Stop");
                    lastLat = currentLat;
                    lastLon = currentLon;
                    doubleclick = true;
                }
            } else {
                lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
                startStop.setText("Start");
                v.clearAnimation();
                doubleclick = false;
                Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
                //in.putExtra("distance", display.toString());
                startActivity(in);
                display.setText("0.0km");
            }

        }
    });
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // start location manager
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Get last location
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // Request new location
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

        // Get new location
        Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();


        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    display.setText("0.0km");

}



}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

add these line just before `start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {});`

```
 display.setText("0.0km");
```

**Edited:**

change this line in the locationChanged listener.like this:

```
 // get the current lat and long
    currentLat = loc2.getLatitude();
    currentLon = loc2.getLongitude();
```

Full class will be like this:

```
public class Gps extends Activity {    
TextView display;
Button start;
boolean doubleclick = false;
AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation;
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;
double lastLon = 0;
double lastLat = 0;
double distance;
Animation animRotate;
TextView startStop;

LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.anim_rotate);

lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
lm.removeUpdates(Loclist); 
display.setText("0.0km");

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!doubleclick) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                enabled = lm
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (loc == null) {
                        display.setText("No GPS location found");
                    } else {
                        // set Current latitude and longitude
                        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
                        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

                    }
                    // Set the last latitude and longitude
                    startStop.setText("Stop");
                    lastLat = currentLat;
                    lastLon = currentLon;
                    doubleclick = true;
                }
            } else {
                lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
                startStop.setText("Start");
                v.clearAnimation();
                doubleclick = false;
                Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
                //in.putExtra("distance", display.toString());
                startActivity(in);
                display.setText("0.0km");
            }

        }
    });
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // start location manager
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Get last location
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // Request new location
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

        // Get new location
        Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
        currentLon = loc.getLongitude();


        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    display.setText("0.0km");

}



}
```

Comment: thank you brother. I can set text view 0.0km but my problem is when I walk again it calculate distance from previous distance. Suppose In previous it was 3.50km and after run application second time it shows 3.51km, 3.52km....but it should be 0.01km, 0.02km like this. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: So, there is no use of these lines: Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER); and Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER); lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist); and LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: Can you please tell me why I used Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER); this line. Can I use currentLat = loc2 .getLatitude();
currentLon = loc2 .getLongitude(); for current lat and lon?

Comment: What about that these two lines: lastLat=currentLat ;
lastLon=currentLon;?

Comment: remove these lines. As you have already done this in onclick listener.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43397/discussion-between-andru-and-mohammad-rajob)

Comment: andru is right u don't need to write those line. As you are showing distance from the point button was clicked so last known location is that point. Just get current location in on location changed and calculate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

set:

```
   display.setText("0.0km");
```

in `if(!doubleclick)` condition as well.

Also you can use the location object in the argument of `onLocationChanged` as folowing:

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = location.getLatitude();
        currentLon = location.getLongitude();


        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Getting reference to location manager.

```
 Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Location manager keeps track of last known location that you can get directly with this method.

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);
```

This like adds a listener to location change so every time when location changes onLocationChange is called.
Now as you have done it in onclick of a button already no need to do it again. Your listener is attached and will call onLocationChange multiple times.

Comment: So, there is no use of these lines: Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER); and Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);  lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist); and LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: inside onLocationChanged u get the new location same as you get by calling getLastKnownLocation SO yes you don't need to do that again.

Comment: That means the parameter of onLocationChanged "location" and Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER); are same?

Comment: in onlocationchanged both location objects have same value

Comment: Can can you tell me that the first four line in onLocationChanged means in my activity? Plz, sorry for poor question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43398/discussion-between-vipul-mittal-and-mohammad-rajob)